# ASPNET Core and localization with resx files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I cant get my resource files loaded, or some thing else is keeping my app to load correct values.

This is from my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, 
         opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })                    
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("da-DK")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "da-DK", 
    uiCulture: "da-DK");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

And this is from my Controller:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHtmlLocalizer<CustomerController> _localizer;

    public CustomerController(IHtmlLocalizer<CustomerController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public IActionResult MyAccount()
    {
        string test = Language.MyAccount;
        ViewData["Message"] = _localizer["MyAccount"];

        return View();
    }
```

My resource files are located in a folder named Resources in the root of my app, and are called:

- Language.da-DK.resx
- Language.resx

The _localizer["MyAccount"]; 
Will return a string "MyAccount" as if it did not find anything in the localization.

The Language.MyAccount; will return "My account" which is the default value.
No one will find my danish translation of this key.

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added `app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions(...))` to the beginning of `Startup.Configure`? Sounds to me that's what you are missing, since with that added you dont really need `services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i tried it and it did help for the culture issue. 
Now the:
 - string test = Language.MyAccount;
will return the danish text: "Min konto"
But I still cant get the 
 - _localizer["MyAccount"];
to return other than "MyAccount", which is just the key, not any value.

I believe the problem has to do with my resource file not beeing loaded correctly

Any suggestion on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i figured it out, partly helped by Daniel J. G.
Yes, i needed to have the

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions(...))
```

in the Configure part of my Startup.cs.

But the thing that made the _localizer actually find the resource file, was changing the namespace of the resx.designer file.

in stead of

```
namespace AO.Customer.Resources
```

it should be

```
namespace AO.Customer
```

The Resources part of the namespace was added by the service it self.

Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 0):

For using _localizer["MyAccount"] you have to have the resource files named as the type specified in **IHtmlLocalizer< *here* >** .

Language.da-DK.resx , Language.resx have to be named **CustomerController.da-DK.resx, CustomerController.en.resx**

Take a look over the official documentation for .net core localization [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)